# Javascript - create Element <hr> with inline style

Tags: javascript, css, function, ckeditor

I would like to modify the horizontalrule plugin of ckeditor:

```
...
exec: function( editor ) {
        var hr = editor.document.createElement( 'hr' );
        editor.insertElement( hr );
    },

    allowedContent: 'hr',
    requiredContent: 'hr'
};
...
```

This plugin generates:

```
<hr />
```

But I would like to get sg. like:

```
<hr style="color:#FFF; height:2px;" />
```

Can anyone help me out how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
hr.style.color = "#FFF";
hr.style.height = "2px";
```

You can do this to the `hr` variable at pretty much any time.

Comment: i tried this allready but it is not working. it seems to be a specific problem with ckeditor